# How to map string values to HTML id

Tags: javascript, string, split

I need to map string values to HTML `id`

```
// values coming from JSON:

selectedMapLocation = 'status=Completed Response=76'

// I have replaced all instances of '=' with ' ' in the generated string:

var spceInBetween = selectedMapLocation.replace(/=/g, ' ');
```

So the output will be:

```
// spceInBetween = "status Completed Response 76"
```

I need to map these string values to HTML `id`. 
Content will be dynamic, so I can't use the `slice()` method here

Intended output:

```
<div id="content1">status</div>
<div id="content2">Completed</div>
<div id="content3">Response</div>
<div id="content4">76</div>
```

What I have tried so far:

```
document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML = spceInBetween[0];

// returning value 's'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: json will be generated by some other region, so i really dont have control on that.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something. Are you looking for `var spceInBetween = selectedMapLocation.replace(/=/g, ' ').split(' ');`?

Comment: If you can't guarantee your values are going to be consistent you're going to be writing code for _all_ cases of returned data. You should ensure that you're receiving JSON that is consistent.

Comment: @timolawl thanks for pointing that, i have fixed it

Comment: @Andy i am trying, but they are not much supportive.

Comment: My point is: if you can't be sure about the data you're receiving how do you expect to write code to consume it, or expect answers here to help if the data keeps changing. Am I missing something?

Comment: If that was the issue, you can simplify the line above to `var spceInBetween = selectedMapLocation.split(/=|\s/);`

Comment: @Andy data will be same, there will be 4 words each time, status Completed Response 76, in this number might change and status can be incomplete. i hope you got the point

Comment: You can use `split` then.

Comment: @timolawl , your suggestion worked. could you please put it as a answer, so that i can make it right answer

Comment: @Andy thanks for the answers, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa, I think I just added to the confusion :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-liner for your problems:

```
var spceInBetween = selectedMapLocation.split(/=|\s/);
```

Comment: i have found one more issue, in another JSON, i am getting values as '"catvar=Site 1↵Response=49"', out put it is generating 'spceInBetween = ["catvar", "Site", "1", "Response", "49"]', so now it is showing 5 values, any idea how to fix this

Comment: Do you only want the values between the `=` sign excluding the spaces, or do you want for example `catvar` equal to `Site 1`?

Comment: `/=|\s(?![\s\S]+\s)/` this should solve your issue, assuming your desired output is the second case.

Comment: Thank you, issue is sorted out now.  i really appreciate your knowledge, keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

With your String corresponding to your data, you can use the split() method, in order to get an array with each word.
refer to : [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Then just have to put each value inside your HTML `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  document.getElementById("content"+(i+1).toString()).innerHTML = spceInBetween[i];
}
```